# BFS for Maze C++ Segmentation Fault error

Tags: c++, queue, breadth-first-search

I am trying to create a BFS for a maze that will stop when a certain point is reached. While testing it I'm running into a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I am trying to modify the code I found on this [site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-in-a-binary-maze/). The main differences between what I am trying to do and the code in that site are that I do not need to output the distance traveled so and I am also supposed to output the order in the queue the vertices are in the inside of the matrix. For example, the output should be the following:

[What the output of the program should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXc2v.png)

The Hashes represent vertices that do not get added to the queue I am not too concerned with them as of now due to this error that is stopping me from going forward.

Here is my code thus far:

```
#include <queue> 
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ROW 8
#define COL 11

struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};


bool isValid(int x, int y) 
{ 
    // return true if row number and column number 
    // is in range 
    return (x >= 0) && (x< ROW) && 
           (y >= 0) && (y < COL); 
} 

int rowNum[] = {-1, 0, 0, 1}; 
int colNum[] = {0, -1, 1, 0}; 

int BFS(int mat[][COL], Point src, Point dest) 
{ 

    int order = 1;
    // Mark the source cell as visited

   bool visited[ROW][COL];

   memset(visited, false, sizeof visited); 


   visited[src.x][src.y] = true;


    // Create a queue for BFS 
  queue <Point> vertices;

  // Enqueue source cell 

  vertices.push(src);
    // Do a BFS starting from source cell

    while(visited[dest.x][dest.y] != true){

        Point current = vertices.front();

        vertices.pop();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        { 

            int row = current.x + rowNum[i]; 
            int col = current.y + colNum[i]; 

            // if adjacent cell is valid, has path and 
            // not visited yet, enqueue it. 

            if (isValid(row, col) == true && (mat[row][col]) &&  
               !visited[row][col]) 
            { 
                cout << "Hi" << endl;
                // mark cell as visited and enqueue it 
                visited[row][col] = true;
                mat[row][col] = order;
                order++;
                vertices.push(current);
                cout << vertices.front().x;
                cout << vertices.front().y;
            } 
            else {

            }
        } 
    }

     return -1;
} 

int main() 
{ 

    int mat[ROW][COL] = 
    { 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 


    }; 

    Point source = {0, 0}; 
    Point dest = {3, 4}; 

    BFS(mat, source, dest);

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << mat[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

I did some troubleshooting beforehand and have found that the error most likely is caused by this spot right here:

```
if (isValid(row, col) == true && (mat[row][col]) &&  
               !visited[row][col]) 
            { 

                // mark cell as visited and enqueue it 
                visited[row][col] = true;
                mat[row][col] = order;
                order++;
                vertices.push(current);
                cout << vertices.front().x;
                cout << vertices.front().y;
            }
```

I assume that because I set up a bunch of output messages (you may notice the cout "Hi's") to occur at certain points in the cause to find the source of the error and that is where it led me.

Any help is appreciated and just to be clear i am trying to find out why i am getting the segmentation fault error.

Thank you.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger. I did and this line caused an error: `Point current = vertices.front();` This happens the 2nd time through the `while` loop when `vertices.size() == 0`.....Helpful reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: in your while loop you should add condition  && !vertices.empty()

Comment: Interesting fun fact: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` includes pretty much the entire freaking standard library. That makes including anything else from the standard library, `<queue>` and `<iostream>` for example, unnecessary. But before you start celebrating, not that this is utter overkill and likely kills your build times--the exact opposite of what `<bits/stdc++.h>` is intended to do. This is because it's not being used correctly. [It should not be used directly at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: also a lil help i think you meant to do                 vertices.push({row,col}); inside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, one of the best errors in programming, the dreaded `segmentation fault`! Logging to `stdout` is one way to debug, but you can make your own life a lot easier by using a debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Let's say your executable is called `bfs`, and it produced a core dump called `core.bfs.12345` (`12345` was the process's PID). Invoke `gdb` like this:

```
$ gdb ./bfs core.bfs.12345
```

Immediately upon entering, `gdb` will tell you *where* your program crashed—no print statements needed! Here's what it should look like:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000400d3e in BFS (mat=0x7fffffffd950, src=..., dest=...) at ../bfs/bfs.cxx:54
54              Point current = vertices.front();
```

Essentially, it's telling you to look at line 54 (your line number may be different) where you've called `queue<Point>::front()`. But, if a queue is empty, calling `front()` is *undefined behavior*.

It seems like the rest of your code is pretty much on track. I'd encourage you to rethink the `while` loop condition. Perhaps, there is a 'safer' way to know whether or not to keep searching.

Comment: Good info, +1, but it should be noted that the Asker can also run their program in gdb and use gdb to control the execution of the program, running it instruction by instruction if that tight a grain is required, and watch the changes each step makes in the state of the program by inspecting the variables. The dump file tells you what happened, but gdb allows you to see how the program got there. Some implementations of gdb even allow you to run the program backwards, and that's very useful.

Comment: I was able to get it working. I had to get rid of the && (mat[row][col]) in the if statement within the For loop that is within the while loop. Also, I changed the while loop condition too !vertices.empty() and have a conditional within the loop to check if the destination is reached. Thank You.